# ping subdomains without the full path

Tags: domain-name-system

I want to be able to -

```
ping x.<myuniversity>.com
```

by just

```
ping x
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By correctly setting the search domain on any UNIX box or the domain suffix on any Windows box.

Comment: Good answer, he could also add the machine to his host file too if he fancied.

Comment: Or he could add the search domains to his dhcp server. Then every client (after getting a new lease) would have the search domain specified.